# How to change height dynamically according to width with aspect ratio 4:3 in vue js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I want to make height change proportionally according to width with aspect ratio 4:3. here the width is 100vw. so I have got the width pixel by this.$refs.imageDiv.clientWidth in mounted hook. now when I log the width and height number in console.log() it logs perfectly. but when I try to change the height dynamically with computed property it doesn't change the height expectedly. what is the propblem?

```
<template>
 <div ref="imageDiv" :style="imageStyle" class="top-blog__photo">
   <img
        :src="require(`../assets/samplePics/${blog.photo}.jpg`)"
        alt="Blog Photo"
      />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
 props: ['blog'],
 data(){
  iWidth: 0,
  iHeight: 0,
 },
 computed: {
  imageStyle(){
   return{
    width: iWidth+"px",
    height: iHeight+"px",
   }
  }
 },
 mounted(){
  if(this.iWidth === 0){
   this.iWidth = this.$refs.imageDiv.clientWidth;
   this.iHeight = this.iWidth / (4/3);
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", ()=>{
   this.iWidth = this.$refs.imageDiv.clientWidth;
   this.iHeight = this.iWidth / (4/3);
  })
 }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.top-blog{
 &__photo{
  img{
   width: 100%;
   height:100%;
   object-fit: cover;
  }
 }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should not use `===` operator for assignment, use just `=` operator like:

```
mounted(){
  if(this.iWidth === 0){
   this.iWidth = this.$refs.imageDiv.clientWidth;
   this.iHeight = this.iWidth / (4/3);
  }
  window.addEventListener("resize", ()=>{
   this.iWidth = this.$refs.imageDiv.clientWidth;
   this.iHeight = this.iWidth / (4/3);
  })
 }
```

Secondly, use `this.iWidth + 'px'` instead of `iWidth` and `this.iHeight + 'px'` instead of `iHeight` in `computed` like this:

```
computed: {
  imageStyle(){
   return{
    width: this.iWidth + 'px',
    height: this.iHeight + 'px',
   }
  }
 },
```

Comment: i was crazy. made lots of mistake

Comment: hello sir, I fixed those issues but it doesn't work yet

Comment: In computed, you have used `width: iWidth+"px", height: iHeight+"px",` you must use `this` for  `iWidth` and `iHeight` like this: `width: this.iWidth + 'px',` and `height: this.iHeight + 'px',`

Comment: another thing i missed out 

Answer (score 0):

If your app is going to be used in modern-enough browsers, you can use the `aspect-ratio` CSS property:

```css
.mydiv {
  width: 250px;
  aspect-ratio: 4 / 3;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
</div>
```